# Tracking promise chains in NEAR smart contract protocol

Tags: nearprotocol

NEAR protocol is sharded and transactions between cross-contract calls in shards are final. In some cases, it would make sense to identify longer transaction chains, especially if the promise chain hits the same contract twice (re-entrancy).

Let's imagine a chain of promises: Alice wants to buy a token and the trade is routed through multiple smart contracts and hits one contract in the chain twice.

```
Alice (user) (tx 1) -> 
exchange contract (triggers promise 1) -> 
aggregator contract (triggers promise 2) -> 
pool contact (triggers promise 3) -> 
exchange contract (again)
```

The exchange contract can identify Alice's account with `signer_account_id`. However can the exchange contract know about the re-entrancy, namely `tx 1` or `promise 1`, and is it possible to resolve or infer this from the smart contract execution context, so that the exchange would know it is already processing trade for Alice?

Note that Alice may have two chain of promises being processed at the same time, so `signer_account_id` is not enough uniquely to identify the chain of promises.

I am looking in [VMContext](https://docs.rs/near-vm-logic/0.3.2/near_vm_logic/struct.VMContext.html) and trying to figure out how this is possible.

Comment: Good question. In a smart contract context you don't see a the transaction (eg tx_hash) and you don't know receipts (this is only available in unit tests). So I guess it's not possible. You can only check if the transaction arrived from signer or from someone else.

Comment: But does the NEAR itself have this information avaible? Because blockchain explorers also need to know to be able to visualise how different smart contracts interacted based on a given transaction.

Comment: The explorer depends on the indexer solution to extra receipts. Also there is an experimental TX status API coming that will return all receipts, so you can track entire chain.

A contract doesn't have much context except for `signer_id`, `signer_public_key` and `predecessor_id`. So it only knows who originated the transaction and who called the contract directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the contract environment, you have to pass all the necessary information through arguments.

Off-chain you can use [NEAR Indexer](https://github.com/nearprotocol/nearcore/tree/master/chain/indexer) or JSONRPC [`EXPERIMENTAL_tx_status`](https://docs.near.org/docs/api/rpc-experimental#transaction-status-with-receipts) method to get all the receipts and their outcomes